# Spring Integration - Aggregate Scattered Messages

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration app that puts incoming files onto a channel. From there I'd like to be able to send the same file to two different processing pipelines (one archiving to S3, another parsing the contents) and later have a downstream component that can recognise when both have been successfully processed, and thus delete the actual local file.

The semantics are like if I needed a Splitter/Aggregator, but instead of splitting the message I need to duplicate it.

Is there any way to achieve this with available components, or will it require some custom classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>` (with `apply-sequence="true"`) will work similarly to a splitter - however both subscribers to the channel will get the SAME `File` object. By default the two branches will be executed serially but you can introduce an ExecutorChannel if you want to process in parallel.

If you want each subscriber to get a different `File` object, you could add a transformer...

`<transformer ... expression="new java.io.File(payload.absolutePath)" />`

Comment: Gary you are, as ever, a star!

Comment: After this, I think you are on the right track with using an aggregator to test when both processes are done. Aggregate on some unique key that your pub-sub channel listeners will emit when they are done (filename?) and set a release-strategy-expression of "#this.size() eq 2". Make sure to configure a MessageGroupStoreReaper to deal w/ situations where one of the processes fails.

Comment: Actually, apply-sequence will add sequence size, sequence number and standard correlationId headers.

Comment: That means the standard correlation and release strategies can be used.